# Retrieve mobile number from contact

Tags: android, contacts

I want to retrieve the mobile number from the contacts (I want to send an sms). Here my code:

```
//Selecting the contact
        Button buttonPickContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pickcontact);
        buttonPickContact.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_PICK_CONTACT);
            }});


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Cursor cursor = null;
        mName.setText(context.getString(R.string.not_available));
        mNumber.setText(context.getString(R.string.not_available));

        if(requestCode == RQS_PICK_CONTACT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Log.d(TAG, "requestCode, resultCode, data ok"); 
            Uri uri = data.getData(); 
            try{
                String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
//              cursor =  getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor =  getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                Log.d(TAG, "Trying to retrieve the name and the number"); 
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String hasNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 

                Log.d(TAG, "hasNumber "+hasNumber); 
                mName.setText(name);

                if(hasNumber.trim().equals("1")){
                    Log.d(TAG, "contact has telephone number"); 
                    //set name and number
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    mNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                CharSequence text = context.getString(R.string.cannot_choose_contact); 
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
            if(cursor!= null && !cursor.isClosed()){
                cursor.close(); 
            }
        }else{
            CharSequence text = context.getString(R.string.cannot_choose_contact); 
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

I am getting: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from CursorWindow...

How do I get the phone number - am I trying to retrieve it from the right column?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed data for a contact is contained in a separate table from the main contact itself (see the [Contacts API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) for more detail). Since you're sending an SMS, it might be more useful to only get the contacts who have a phone number associated, so you might as well go straight for the table which contains phone numbers. For the URI, I use:

```
CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```

Then you don't have to worry about `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER`. At a glance, the rest of your code looks right or very close.  If you wanted to continue down your original path, you'd have to do a separate query on this table anyway, but provide it the ID of the contact that you initially found.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a CursorLoader to do queries. Always. If you continue to do queries on the UI thread, eventually you'll run into a situation where you hang the system and get an ANR.
2. You're requesting the user to pick contacts from the Contacts table, so you'll get back a URI that points to a contact in Contacts.
3. A trick for handling this is to strip the contact's LOOKUP_KEY from the returned URI using
   Uri.getLastPathSegment(). Then search ContactsContract.Data for the LOOKUP_KEY and the
   MIMETYPE value CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE. Based on your code, this would be:

mLookupKey = uri.getLastPathSegment();
String SELECTION = Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ? " +
    " AND " +
    Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {
    mLookupKey,
    Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
};
...